OpenVpn при включении не открываются сайты
На сервере установил openVpn и сгенерировал ключи. На клиенте выполняется подключение, видно что трафик идет, но сайты не открываются, пинг не проходит, кажется сервер просто не пропускает ничего.
Настройки сервера:
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
keepalive 10 120

remote-cert-tls client
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0

cipher AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn–status.log
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1

topology subnet

Настройки клиента:
client

remote {IP сервера OpenVPN}

port 1194 

dev tun
proto udp

resolv-retry infinite

nobind
redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp

persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server 

key-direction 1

cipher AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC

verb 4

ca ca.crt
cert client2.crt
key client2.key
tls-auth ta.key 1


Вы действуете из России? многие провайдеры распознают трафик OpenVPN и режут его на периметре. Я пользовался Outline/ShadowSockets с префиксом.

Да, ты прав, OpenVPN не будет работать. Воспользовался AmneziaVPN.

OpenVPN режется, надо пользоваться другими средствами.
